# Bad : modifier in $ (/)

Tags: shell, tcsh

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/my/lib
```

error:

```
Bad : modifier in $ (/)
```

echo $SHELL

```
/bin/tcsh
```

I want to add my library to LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. But Gives the above error.

Comment: Then you should probably use tcsh syntax.

Comment: How can I use it @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams), pointed out you need to [set environment variable](http://www.tcsh.org/EnvironmentVariable) in `tcsh` syntax as

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:"/home/my/lib"
```

Comment: To clarify what's going on here: tcsh allows "variable modifiers" in the form of `$varname:modifier`, so if your variable name is followed by a `:text` you need to use the `${..}` syntax to make it clearer that the `:text` isn't part of the variable modifier.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Assign empty string to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, if the variable is undefined
[ ${?LD_LIBRARY_PATH} -eq 0 ] && setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ""

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/my/lib"
```

**Checking if the Variable is Defined**

If the variable was not previously defined, the simple `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH value` command will fail with an error like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable.`. To prevent this, check the value of `${?LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` ([substitutes](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Variable_substitution.html) the string `1` if name is set, `0` if it is not) and set a default value as it is shown above.

**Using Double Quotes**

Also note the use of double quotes. Suppose the variable contains spaces, e.g.:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/home/user with spaces/lib"
```

Then the command without quotes:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/my/lib
```

will fail with the following error:

```
setenv: Too many arguments.
```

In double quotes, however, the value is passed to the command as a single word.